# CSS float help needed

Tags: html, css, css-float

Guys Please help me to solve this floating problem.I tried different methods but anything didn't work for me.[image]

In the html file,Small images are in the global container.Footer placed right below the global container.But now the footer comes to the top.

These are my css-

CSS of images-

```
style="margin-top: 25px; margin-right: 48px; float: right;"<br>
style="margin-top: 25px; margin-right: 48px; float: left;"

#footer_container{
    width: 900px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;    
}     



#global_body_container{
    width: 746px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: #c6c8cc;
    border-style:dashed;
    clear: both;


}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place on the container of the floated elements `overflow: hidden`.

```
#global_body_container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: @alex I tried that but it's not working yet.

.home_icons_left{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 58px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.home_icons_right{
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: @alex what about now?

#global_body_container{
    width: 746px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-color: #c6c8cc;
    border-style:dashed;
    clear: both; 
    overflow: hidden;
    
    
}

Comment: @alex Ya but the problem is it's not working.Now I am going through the script again to find the mistake.

Thank you for your idea alex.

Comment: @Ceylo: You should show the HTML too or maybe put something up on http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

You have `position: absolute;` on your `#footer_container`.  Remove that and then add a clearing `br` under the footer, like so

```
<div id="global_body_container">
    <img>
    <img>
    etc...

    <br style="clear:both;" />

    <div id="footer_container">
         whatever content...
    </div>

</div>


#footer_container{
    width: 900px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;  //REMOVE THIS
    border: solid;    
}
```

Also, you may want to consider adding more to your `border` rule, such as thickness and color, e.g., `border:1px solid black;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new "content container".  Put all your floating images in.  Then place the new container right before your footer_container.

Answer (score 0):

Because all your elements in global_body_container are float, so it cannot wrap those images visually.

A simple solution is add a stub at the end of global_body_container, and let it clear float elements.

```
<div id="global_body_container">
    <img class="left">
    <img class="right">

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

shinkou has mentioned a clearing trick. You can also refer to [clearfix](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/utilities/general/clearfix/) mixin in [compass](http://compass-style.org). The expended css looks like:

```
.clearfix {
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Also refer to discussion in [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Comment: @lan Yang I tried your method but now the footer moved to the right side little bit.mmm no it's located next to the first image from the right side.Also this has expand the width of the site.I mean I have to scroll to view a part of the footer.

Comment: See Jason's answer, you should not have `position: absolute` in the footer.